# ReactJs. the function is called before the state is updated

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I am writing the Snake game app for practice.

I have a changeDirection function which sets the appropriate direction into the state based on arrow click:

```
changeDirection = event => {
  const { direction } = this.state;

  const keyPressed = event.keyCode;

  if (keyPressed === keyCodes.LEFT_KEY && direction !== "right") {
    this.setState({ direction: "left" });
  }
  if (keyPressed === keyCodes.UP_KEY && direction !== "down") {
    this.setState({ direction: "up" });
  }
  if (keyPressed === keyCodes.RIGHT_KEY && direction !== "left") {
    this.setState({ direction: "right" });
  }
  if (keyPressed === keyCodes.DOWN_KEY && direction !== "up") {
    this.setState({ direction: "down" });
  }
}
```

and it works fine, but the problem is in another function.
I am updating the snake's head position based on the direction state. and this function is executed every 1 seconds (with the setInterval) and when the direction is changed the snake's head does not change its direction right away. It does it on the next move.

I get that this is because the new direction state is not yet set when snake moves for the first time but I dont know how to fix this.

here is the repo: 
https://github.com/Dito-Orkodashvili/snake

Comment: Please include all relevant code. It's not possible to say what might be wrong from the code currently in your question.

Comment: I have added the repo link in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
   this.setState({ direction: "down" },anotherFunction());
```

Call your function in the callback of the setState, It will be called after state is updated.

link: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: This seems correct.. Though, if his function is called every second using `setInterval`, the code should just work: 1) `changeDirection()` changes the state. 2) Eventualy, `setInterval` will call the function `changeHeadPosition()`, and it will be after the (1) point. 
So, I don't know why he's having problem.. @Dito Maybe you should show the other function too

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that I am calling that 'anotherFunction' in other place. p.s I placed whole repo link into the original post

Comment: This should be `this.setState({ direction: "down" }, anotherFunction);` unless anotherFunction returns a function

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state of the direction only. This makes the component re-render. Then you update the state of the snake and the component re-render again and then is when you see the head updated.

A solution could be to break down moveSnake function. Use moveSnake only to move the snake once the component renders.

Create another function to update the head and snake state and call it from the keyboard event handler. This way the component will re-render with all the changes in the state at the same time.

Updating the state from the setInterval should also work, like so:

```
newDirection;

startGame = () => {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
     this.moveSnake();
   }, 200);
};

changeDirection = event => {
    const keyPressed = event.keyCode;

    if (keyPressed === keyCodes.LEFT_KEY && direction !== 'right') {
      this.newDirection = 'left';
    }
    if (keyPressed === keyCodes.UP_KEY && direction !== 'down') {
      this.newDirection = 'up';
    }
    if (keyPressed === keyCodes.RIGHT_KEY && direction !== 'left') {
      this.newDirection = 'right';
    }
    if (keyPressed === keyCodes.DOWN_KEY && direction !== 'up') {
      this.newDirection = 'down';
    }
};

moveSnake = () => {
   /* do updates in the snake shape */

   this.setState({
     direction: this.newDirection,
     snake: copyOfSnake
   });
};
```

Comment: That is exactly what is happening, but I think your solution doesn't fit my case. Because I am updating snakes head position every second with using of setInterval. This is how the snake moves. it shifts head one cell forward and removes tail. so if I call this function only in keyDown event then the snake will not move until I press the button. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Then a solution could be to don't update the state directly from the event handler but store the direction value. Then update the state from the setInterval using your direction variable.